# Using Enumeration in constructor of other classes Java

Tags: java, constructor, enumeration

sry for this stupid or maybe simple question. I've never learnt enumerations and now we shall use them and I have no idea of them. I searched for a solution of my problem but I cant find anything... and without the solution and cant continue my code. So it would be awesome if you help me.

I have to open a enum in my package that looks like

```
public enum FuelType 
{
    Gasoline, Diesel    
}
```

Additionally I have a class called car. In this class I have a string description. 
Now I wanna create a constructor that looks like

```
public Car(String description, FuelType fuelType)
{
   ....
}
```

I want to use the enum FuelType in this constructor but I dont know how. I tried nearly everything but nothing worked for me.

Hopefully you can help me! Thanks and regards
Skalk

Comment: Well, what did you try ?

Comment: I think you need to explain what you mean by nothing worked. What exactly went wrong? There is no reason why you can't pass an enum constant to a constructor.

Comment: Ok thats hard to explain^^ I tried a String Fuel in enum and create a constructor in enum but that didnt work. I tried several ways to include the FuelType in my constructor in class Car but nothing worked. I just want to include the enum FuelType in the constructor of my class car but i dont know how.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i got it, you know how to pass `FuelType` parameter to the `Car` constructor, but you don't know how to store it. Is it correct? Is this wat you're looking for?

```
public class Car {
    private String description;
    private FuelType fuelType;

    public Car(String description, FuelType fuelType) {
        this.description = description;
        this.fuelType = fuelType;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ok im ashamed of my knowledge. Thats exactly what i need. I've never had the idea creating a new variable fuelType. Thank you so much! :-) I'm such a bad coder...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Car myCar = new Car("Mercedes", FuelType.Diesel);
```

Make sure you have imported the FuelType class, if it is not in the same package.

Comment: Hey thanks for the fast answer but i dont want to create a new instance. I dont know what i have to write in the constructor that i can create a new instance.       
public Car(String description, FuelType fuelType)  {
 this.description=description;
        ..... 
}
I dont know what i should write instead of '...'